# jQuery Search Page Filter - display category results in search

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a jQuery search filter that shows matching items (within p tags) displayed under their appropriate h4 headings. Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/mfen723/syhaeu9r/14/

The function I am using is:

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#searchInput").on("keyup", function () {
          const value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
          $('#research .noresults, #research h4 , #research p').css('display', 'none');
          const filter_p = $("#research p").filter(function () {
            return ($(this).text().toLowerCase()).indexOf(value) > -1;
          });
          filter_p
            .css('display', 'block')   //<<<<<<<<
            .prevUntil('h4')
            .prev('h4')
            .css('display', 'block');
          $('#research h4')
            .not(filter_p.prevUntil('h4').prev('h4'))
            .nextUntil('.noresults')
            .next('.noresults')
            .css('display', 'block');
        });
      });
```

If 'Abbing' is searched for, for example, two h4 headings are shown with the matching p content beneath them. This works very well. If I search for 'infectious', nothing is displayed as there is no matching p content in the 'Infectious and chronic diseases' section.

How can the function be amended to **also** show searches by category, so if a user searches 'Infectious', for example,  the h4 heading 'Infectious and chronic diseases' is displayed, along with its accompanying p content?

I have tried adding a hidden html tag within the relevant p element, but this hasn't worked.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply filter to `h4` (category) also and implement the show/hide logic base on the content filter for `p` and `h4` as per your need. Find the example in following code snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#searchInput").on("keyup", function () {
          const value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
          $('#research .noresults, #research h4 , #research p').css('display', 'none');
          
          const filter_p = $("#research p").filter(function () {
            return ($(this).text().toLowerCase()).indexOf(value) > -1;
          });
          filter_p
            .css('display', 'block')   //<<<<<<<<
            .prevUntil('h4')
            .prev('h4')
            .css('display', 'block');
          $('#research h4')
            .not(filter_p.prevUntil('h4').prev('h4'))
            .nextUntil('.noresults')
            .next('.noresults')
            .css('display', 'block');
            
            
            const filter_cat = $("#research h4").filter(function () {
            return ($(this).text().toLowerCase()).indexOf(value) > -1;
          });
          filter_cat
            .css('display', 'block')   //<<<<<<<<
            .nextUntil('h4')
            .css('display', 'block');
        });
        
        
       
        
      });
```

```css
.search {
  display: block !important;
  position: relative;
  background-color: var(--bg-light);
}

.search input {
  text-indent: 25px;
}

.search input:focus {
  box-shadow: none;
  border: 2px solid var(grey);
}

.search input.form-control {
  display: block !important;
  width: 700px !important;
}

.search .fa-search {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 15px;
  font-size: 2rem;
  z-index: 12;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="search">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-lg-9 mx-auto" id="research">
      <div class="search my-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control mx-auto" id="searchInput" placeholder="Search by author or keyword">
      </div>
      <h4 class="sub-heading-alt-resources pb-3" id="#methodologies">Research</h4>
      <p>Ricardo R Bartelme, <a href="https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1177/2164956120973634" target="_blank" rel="no-referrer">Anthroposophic Medicine: A Short Monograph and Narrative Review—Foundations, Essential Characteristics, Scientific Basis, Safety, Effectiveness and Misconceptions</a>, published 29 December 2020 in Pub Med, doi 10.1177/2164956120973634</p>
      <p>Mehl A, Brauer D, Didwiszus A, Gelin-Kröz B, Pranga D, Zerm R, Gutenbrunner C (2020), <a href="https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S155083072030224X" target="_blank" rel="no-referrer">The Anthroposophic Art Therapy Assessment Paint (AART-ASSESS-P): A peer-report instrument to assess patients’ pictorial expression during Anthroposophic Painting Therapy</a></p>
      <p>Lees J (2001) <a href="https://www.researchgate.net/publication/238318617_Reflexive_action_research_Developing_knowledge_through_practice">Reflexive Action Research: Developing Knowledge Through Practice: Counselling and Psychotherapy Research</a> (2001), August 2001, Counselling and Psychotherapy Research 1(2):132-138, <a href="https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1080/14733140112331385178" target="_blank" rel="no-referrer">DOI:10.1080/14733140112331385178</a></p>
      <p>Shlonsky A and Gobbs L, <a href="https://www.researchgate.net/publication/247903648_Will_the_Real_Evidence-Based_Practice_Please_Stand_Up_Teaching_the_Process_of_Evidence-Based_Practice_to_the_Helping_Professions" target="_blank" rel="no-referrer">Will the Real Evidence-Based Practice Please Stand Up? Teaching the Process of Evidence-based Practice to the Helping Professions. Brief Treatment and Criss Intervention.</a> Vol 4. No. 2., January 2004, Brief Treatment and Crisis Intervention 4(2):137-153, <a href="http://mr.crossref.org/iPage?doi=10.1093%2Fbrief-treatment%2Fmhh011" target="_blank" rel="no-referrer">DOI:10.1093/brief-treatment/mhh011</a></p>
      <p>Kienle G S, Albonico H U, Baars E, Hamre H J, Zimmermann P, Kiene H (2013). <a href="https://www.hsleiden.nl/binaries/content/assets/hsl/lectoraten/antroposofische-gezondheidszorg/artikelgaiham.pdf" target="_blank" rel="no-referrer">(pdf, 882 KB )Anthroposophic Medicine: An Integrative Medical System Originating in Europe. ( pdf, 882 KB )</a> Global Advances In Health And Medicine November 2013, Volume 2, Number 6</p>
      <p>Abbing A, Ponstein A, Kienle G, Gruber H, Baars E (2016) The CARE-AAT Guideline: <a href="https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/17454832.2016.1170054?needAccess=true">Development and testing of a consensus-based guideline for case reports in anthroposophic art therapy.</a><a href="https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/17454832.2016.1170054?needAccess=true" target="_blank" rel="no-referrer">International Journal of Art Therapy, DOI: 10.1080/17454832.2016.1170054</a></p>
          <h4 class="sub-heading-alt-resources pt-3" id="pregnancy">Pregnancy, Birth and Early childhood</h4>
          <p>Gollmer B (15.01.2019) <a href="https://www.anthromedics.org/PRA-0779-EN" target="_blank">Painting Therapy in Pregnancy and Preparation for Childbirth</a> (professional information)</p>
          <p>Gollmer B (19.07.2019) <a href="https://www.anthromedics.org/PRA-0781-EN" target="_blank">Painting Therapy in Pregnancy and Birth Preparation</a> (parent information)</p>
          <p>Bissegger M (07.06.2019) <a href="https://www.anthromedics.org/PRA-0805-EN" target="_blank">Music Therapy for Premature Infants and their Mothers</a></p>
          <p>Bissegger M (02.01.2020) <a href="https://www.anthromedics.org/PRA-0907-EN" target="_blank">Music Therapy for Babies and Toddlers</a></p>
          <p>Bissegger M (02.01.2020) <a href="https://www.anthromedics.org/PRA-0905-EN" target="_blank">Singing and Music for Babies and Toddlers</a> (parent information) ​</p>
          <h4 class="sub-heading-alt-resources" id="child-health">Child Health</h4>
          <p>Hamre HJ et al. (2009) <a href="https://www.researchgate.net/publication/26309949_Anthroposophic_therapy_for_children_with_chronic_disease_A_two-year_prospective_cohort_study_in_routine_outpatient_settings" target="_blank">Anthroposophic therapy for children with chronic disease: a two-year Prospective Cohort Study in Routine Outpatient Settings</a>. BMC Pediatr 2009; 9:39. DOI 10.1186/1471-2431-9-39</p>
          <p>Abbing A, Krantz B, Simon E, Heynen E, De Witte M and Van Hooren S (2020). <a href="https://www.crd.york.ac.uk/prospero/display_record.php?ID=CRD42020162709" target="_blank">Effectiveness of Music Therapy Interventions in Reducing Behavioural and Emotional Problems Among Children</a>. PROSPERO 2020. CRD42020162709</p>
          <p>Baars E W, Koster E B, Schoorel E P (2012).<a href="https://www.researchgate.net/publication/282149760_Client_experiences_with_an_integrated_conventional_and_anthroposophic_approach_at_the_Kindertherapeuticum_in_Zeist" target="_blank">Client experiences with an integrated conventional and anthroposophic approach at the Kindertherapeuticum in Zeist</a>. Der Merkurstab, 4:335-338</p>
          <p>Niemeijer M H, Baars E W, Hoekman J, Ruijssenaars A J J M (2018) <a href="https://www.researchgate.net/publication/330164731_An_Instrument_for_Dimensional_Diagnosis_of_a_Child_Constitution_ICC_Individualizing_the_Care_for_Children_with_Developmental_Disorders" target="_blank">An instrument for dimensional diagnosis of a child’s constitution (ICC)</a>. International Journal of Complementary & Alternative Medicine, Issue 2-2018.</p>
          <p>Niemeijer M H, Baars E W, Hoekman J, and Ruijssenaars A J J M (2018). <a href="https://eur01.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fjournal.julypress.com%2Findex.php%2Fijsn%2Farticle%2Fdownload%2F531%2F401&data=04%7C01%7Cbaars.e%40hsleiden.nl%7C806fd3cb33754902a30908d92b842ba7%7C850f9344e078467e9c5e84d82f208ac7%7C1%7C0%7C637588668989923315%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C1000&sdata=RinbscVUm36ksES%2F4dpv3pCSyMP6bzjQFJ8WPTt0yBM%3D&reserved=0" target="_blank">Validity and Reliability of the Instrument for Assessing the Child’s Constitution (ICC): Individualising Processes in Diagnosing Children With a Developmental Disorder</a> . International Journal of Studies in Nursing, 3(3), 172.</p>
          <h4 class="sub-heading-alt-resources" id="infectious">Infectious and chronic diseases</h4>
          <p>Hamre H J. Witt C M, Glockmann A, Ziegler R (July 2007) <a href="https://www.researchgate.net/publication/6158737_Anthroposophic_Art_Therapy_in_Chronic_Disease_A_Four-Year_Prospective_Cohort_Study" target="_blank">Anthroposophic Art Therapy in Chronic Disease: A Four-Year Prospective Cohort Study</a> The Journal of Science and Healing 3(4):365-71, Doi: 10.1016/j.explore.2007.04.008,</p>
          <p>Hamre H J et al. (2004). <a href="https://www.researchgate.net/publication/8374153_Anthroposophic_therapies_in_chronic_disease_The_Anthroposophic_Medicine_Outcomes_Study_AMOS" target="_blank">Anthroposophic therapies in chronic disease: The Anthroposophic Medicine Outcomes Study (AMOS)</a>. European Journal of Medical Research 2004; 9:351-360</p>
          <p>Hamre H J et al. (2007) <a href="https://www.researchgate.net/publication/6158737_Anthroposophic_Art_Therapy_in_Chronic_Disease_A_Four-Year_Prospective_Cohort_Study" target="_blank">Anthroposophic Art Therapy in Chronic Disease: a four-year prospective cohort study</a>. Explore (NY). 2007 Nov-Dec;3(6):553</p>
          <p>Hamre HJ et al. (2013). <a href="https://www.researchgate.net/publication/249318203_Long-term_outcomes_of_anthroposophic_treatment_for_chronic_disease_A_four-year_follow-up_analysis_of_1510_patients_from_a_prospective_observational_study_in_routine_outpatient_settings" target="_blank">Long-term Outcomes of Anthroposophic Treatment for Chronic Disease: A four-year follow-up Analysis of 1510 Patients from a Prospective Observational Study in routine outpatient settings</a> BMC Research Notes. 2013;6(1):269. DOI: <a href="https://doi.org/10.1186/1756-0500-6-269" target="_blank">https://doi.org/10.1186/1756-0500-6-269</a></p>
          <h4 class="sub-heading-alt-resources" id="covid">COVID-19</h4>
          <p>Martin D, Soldner G (2020) <a href="https://www.anthromedics.org/PRA-0971-EN" target="_blank">A synthesis review of current status and proposal of a registry study to overcome social polarization tendencies and answer open research questions</a></p>
          <p>Soldner G, Breitkreuz T (2020) <a href="https://www.anthromedics.org/PRA-0939-EN" target="_blank">COVID-19</a> </p>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```